# How to inject a keyvalue properties file with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, properties, io

I have a keyvalue properties file that contains error codes and their error messages.

I'd like to inject this file on application startup, so that I can make lookups on the injected property without having to read the file.

The following is just pseudocode, is there anything in `Spring` that could create this setup?

```
@Value(location = "classpath:app.properties")
private Properties props;
```

whereas app.properties contains:

```
error1=test
error2=bla
...
```

If not, how could I achieve this without spring?

Comment: You could do that with `resourceBundle` in spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of "kocko", the following setup works as expected, only annotation config:

```
@Bean(name = "errors")
public PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("errors.properties"));
    return bean;
}

@Resource(name = "errors")
private Properties errors;
```

Or if the resource should not be provided as a bean, but simply be loaded inside a `@Component`:

```
@Component
public class MyLoader {
    private Properties keys;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("app.properties"));
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        keys = bean.getObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Nice! It's actually pretty easy, but I'm too sleepy and didn't think of this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can first declare the properties files as a such, by using `<util:properties>` in your Spring configuration:

```
<util:properties id="messages" location="classpath:app.properties" />
```

This registers a bean with name `messages`, which you can autowire/inject in other beans.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("messages")
private Properties props;
```

More info:

- [The < util: > schema in Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties)

Comment: Is this possible without xml configuration? (I have and like to stick to annotation based configuration only)

Comment: I think so, yes. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219097/spring-utilproperties-injection-via-annotations-into-a-bean

Comment: It's cool that you stick to the annotation based configuration, which allows you to **minimize** the xml configuration, not get rid of it :)

Comment: I would like to do the same, just programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

i am doing it this way in my project

```
  <bean id="myPropertyHolder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
         <value>classpath:myApplication.properties</value> 
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Then use the property like below

```
<property name="testProperty" value="${testProperty}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@M Sach
You can also use property location instead locations, so you don't have to use list