# How to inject a properties file using Spring?

Tags: java, spring

How can I inject the following key-value file as a `Properties` variable or `HashMap` directly, using `spring`?

src/main/resources/myfile.properties:

```
key1=test
someotherkey=asd
(many other key-value pairs)
```

None of the following worked:

```
@Value("${apikeys}")
private Properties keys;

@Resource(name = "apikeys")
private Properties keys;
```

Sidenote: I don't know the keys inside the properties file in advance. So I cannot use `@PropertyResource` injection.

Comment: Which spring version you are using?

Comment: `spring-boot.1.5.3`, thus newest `spring 4`

Comment: Not possible out of the box(You need a separate class to do so) if you wish to declare it like how you have done.  But if you can declare it like a String 
`propertyMap= {key1:test, key2:test2}`, then you can use SPEL to directly map to a Map

Comment: @membersound is `@Value` a mandatory requirement? Would you consider using `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Comment: `@Value` is not mandatory, I just wanted to show what I tried and did not work. I'm happy with any solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to inject a keyvalue properties file with Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820624/how-to-inject-a-keyvalue-properties-file-with-spring)

Answer (score 2):

One way you could try to achieve this is by creating a bean in your configuration file:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, String> myFileProperties() {
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myfile");
    return bundle.keySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, bundle::getString));
}
```

Then you can easily inject this bean into your service e.g.

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, String> myFileProperties;
```

(Consider using constructor injection)

Also don't forget to

`@PropertySource("classpath:myfile.properties")`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `Value` annotation first you need to define in your `applicationContext.xml` below bean

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:myfile.properties"></property>
</bean>
```

Once you define your property file , you can use `Value` annotation.

Comment: I'd prefer annotation based configuration as spring4 is not using xml config anymore.

Comment: oh ok , sorry didn't notice that , also still it might be useful who is before 4.x.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Annotation [PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

**Sample:**

```
@PropertySource("myfile.properties")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    ApplicationProperties appProperties() {
        ApplicationProperties bean = new ApplicationProperties();
        bean.setKey1(environment.getProperty("key1"));
        bean.setsomeotherkey(environment.getProperty("someotherkey"));
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is useful only for static values. @membersound added an edit after your answer that the keys in property file are unknown.