# Is Autowired in xml is not for primitive datatype

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am trying like this and not using annotation in my bean class. I want to set the value inside string bean using autowire by type. But the value is coming as Null. when I am using a custom object (not a primitive data type), I am getting the value which I am placing inside the referred bean. Could any one highlighy on this?

## Bean.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<bean id="salesorder" class="com.demo.bean.salesorder" autowire="byType">
<property name="orderID" value="100010"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="orderdesc" class="java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg value="This is my first reference use in spring"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What is `null`? Show us a complete example. What is `salesorder`? How do you retrieve your beans?

Answer (score 0):

I am reasonably certain you can't do this.  I think you can only inject real objects, not sorta kinda faux native object-like things.  Examples: String, Long, etc.

I suggest if you really want to do this you use a util:properties construct.  It's not exactly the same thing but I think you can get what you want.

[util:roperties example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219097/spring-utilproperties-injection-via-annotations-into-a-bean)

OR possibly a map?
Example:

```
<util:map id="filtersByFlag">
   <entry key="${flag.even}" value-ref="filtersForEven" />
   <entry key="${flag.odd}" value-ref="filtersForOdd" />
</util:map>
```